# Stuck on layout format

Tags: android

Recently did a refreshers course in Android. I see that they changed a lot with the update. I have run into a few problems which I hope someone can help me figure out. The course gave me this [code](https://gist.github.com/udacityandroid/832I42daf8a43b743d05e98733a35b19f) to be able to add in a button and make it activate for Android. However, this code is slightly outdated and I have attached the screenshot of the code I tried to fix according to what Andriod wants. think most of the problem is that with the new andriod sutidio I am working with this layout :androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

I would like to know in the ain activity how can I fix the problem in the screenshot attached to get this right. Please help because I can't move forward until I figure out the problem. I would like to know how do I change the "R" to the right code for constraint layout.

[image: Android studio]

Comment: Try With Android Studio Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you have error of R, then follow below steps.

1. Go to File menu in android studio and click on Invalidate cache / restart option.
2. Then clean your project.